# How to configure log4j to send logs to stdout as JSON in ksqldb?

Tags: log4j, ksqldb

I'm using `ksqldb` deployed inside a `kubernetes` pod, that automatically sends console output to `logstash` and `kibana`.

I'm trying to read the server logs but the output is not great, especially when a stack trace occurs.
It would be better if I could output my logs as JSON. So, I got to this `log4j.properties`, but could not find how to do it.
This is the default file.

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.appender.streams=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.streams.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.streams.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n
```

I tried to use the confluent json layout, but it did not work as expected.

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=io.confluent.common.logging.log4j.StructuredJsonLayout
```

I had some ideas of how to do it, but most of them sounded too complicated for something so simple.

Comment: How are  you running ksqldb? With the `confluentinc/ksqldb-server` docker image?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the image `confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.12.0`

Comment: any progress. Even if it says `StructuredJsonLayout`, actual message it is expecting to be a json but if its plain string it doesn’t apply double quotes. Is there any parameter to add the quotes to message field, or jsonify actual message?

Comment: Hi. You can ask for this info on their slack. It helped me a lot.